# The type new Comparator(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.compare(Object, Object)

Tags: java, comparator

please help her. I had an error in

```
  Collections.sort(var4, new Comparator() {
     public int compare(TreeMap var1, TreeMap var2) {
        return ((String)var1.get("col_3")).compareTo((String)var2.get("col_3"));
     }
  });
```

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?

Comment: Could you describe more what you want to do and what error you're getting? What is var4?

Comment: sorry I have not finished the problem persists error. 
My application is not running. is his code. please help

public void Listme() { FormulList var1 = new FormulList(); ArrayList var2 = new ArrayList(); var2.addAll(var1.FormulL()); ArrayList var4 = new ArrayList(); String[] var5 = new String[]{"col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4"};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way by adding to Comparator ,

```
Collections.sort(var4, new Comparator<TreeMap>() 
{
     public int compare(TreeMap var1, TreeMap var2) 
     {
        return ((String)var1.get("col_3")).compareTo((String)var2.get("col_3"));
     }
});
```